# Sum of subquery with sum

Tags: mysql, subquery, sum

I've a query which give me a column with totals, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM( BoekRegelBedrag ) AS total, 
    BoekRegelPeriode, BoekRegelGrootboekNr, 
    BaOmschrijving, BaSoort 
FROM BoekstukRegels 
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT BaOmschrijving, BaSoort, BaGbNumber 
        FROM balansen 
        WHERE BauserId = 45 
        GROUP BY BaGbNumber 
    ) tbl ON BoekRegelGrootboekNr = BaGbNumber 
WHERE BoekregelUserId = 45 
    AND BoekRegelPeriode BETWEEN '201201' AND '201212' 
    AND BaSoort = 2 
GROUP BY BoekRegelGrootboekNr
```

What I want now is to sum those results of the given query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier to your existing query. That will return an extra row, with NULL values in your regular columns and the desired grand total value in your `total` column.

```
SELECT SUM( BoekRegelBedrag ) AS total, BoekRegelPeriode, BoekRegelGrootboekNr, BaOmschrijving, BaSoort 
    FROM BoekstukRegels 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT BaOmschrijving, BaSoort, BaGbNumber 
                       FROM balansen 
                       WHERE BauserId = 45 
                       GROUP BY BaGbNumber )tbl 
            ON BoekRegelGrootboekNr = BaGbNumber 
    WHERE BoekregelUserId = 45 
        AND BoekRegelPeriode BETWEEN '201201' AND '201212' 
        AND BaSoort = 2 
    GROUP BY BoekRegelGrootboekNr
    WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: I've some negative values in my table, is it possible to make those positive before the sum?

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen You could use the [ABS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function to return the absolute value: `SELECT SUM(ABS(BoekRegelBedrag)) AS total...`

Comment: Your the master! Thanks again!

Comment: One last question because i was to fast. Is it possible to use that ABS function after the SUM and before the ROLLUP. So I only want to make te results of the summed column positive and sum those results.

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen: That is not possible. You'd have to wrap your original query inside of a new query that would do that.

Comment: I'm sorry but how can i do that?

Comment: @LeonvanderVeen: That's probably different enough to warrant a new question.

Comment: Ok I will do that. I tried this: SELECT SUM(b.total) FROM(

SELECT SUM( BoekRegelBedrag ) AS total, BoekRegelPeriode, BoekRegelGrootboekNr, BaOmschrijving, BaSoort
FROM BoekstukRegels AS b
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT BaOmschrijving, BaSoort, BaGbNumber
FROM balansen WHERE BauserId = 45
GROUP BY BaGbNumber
)tbl ON BoekRegelGrootboekNr = BaGbNumber
WHERE BoekregelUserId = 45
AND BoekRegelPeriode BETWEEN '201201' AND '201212'
AND BaSoort = 2
GROUP BY BoekRegelGrootboekNr
) tbl but it failed. Can you tell me if Im in the right direction?